# Determine distance between two random nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

Given a general tree, I want the distance between two nodes `v` and `w`.

Wikipedia [states the following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor):

> Computation of lowest common ancestors may be useful, for instance, as part of a procedure for determining the distance between pairs of nodes in a tree: the distance from v to w can be computed as the distance from the root to v, plus the distance from the root to w, minus twice the distance from the root to their lowest common ancestor.

Let's say `d(x)` denotes the distance of node `x` from the root which we set to `1`. `d(x,y)` denotes the distance between two vertices `x` and `y`. `lca(x,y)` denotes the lowest common ancestor of vertex pair `x` and `y`.

Thus if we have `4` and `8`, `lca(4,8) = 2` therefore, according to the description above, `d(4,8) = d(4) + d(8) - 2 * d(lca(4,8)) = 2 + 3 - 2 * 1 = 3`. Great, that worked!

However, the case stated above seems to fail for the vertex pair `(8,3)` (`lca(8,3) = 2`) `d(8,3) = d(8) + d(3) - 2 * d(2) = 3 + 1 - 2 * 1 = 2.` This is incorrect however, the distance `d(8,3) = 4` as can be seen on the graph. The algorithm seems to fail for anything that crosses over the defined root.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You have two 2's.  Is that intentional?

Comment: No it wasn't, I've updated the picture!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed  that the `lca(8,3) = 1`, and not `= 2`. Hence the `d(1) == 0` which makes it:

```
d(8,3) = d(8) + d(3) - 2 * d(1) = 3 + 1 - 2 * 0 = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

For the appropriate `2` node, namely the one one the right, `d(lca(8,2))` == 0, not 1 as you have it in your derivation.  The distance from the root--which is the lca in this case--to itself is zero.  So

```
d(8,2) = d(8) + d(2) - 2 * d(lca(8,2)) = 3 + 1 - 2 * 0 = 4
```

The fact that you have two nodes labeled `2` is probably confusing things.

**Edit:** The post has been edited so that a node originally labeled 2 is now labeled 3.  In this case, the derivation is now correct but the statement

```
 the distance d(8,2) = 4 as can be seen on the graph
```

is incorrect, d(8,2) = 2.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the picture. Thus it's `d(8,3) => lca(8,3) = 2`, and `d(8) + d(3) - 2 * d(2) = 3 + 1 - 2 * 1 = 2`, which is incorrect? Why do you would the LCA be the root in this case? It's not really the lowest (=smallest depth) in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting `d(8,3) = 2` (assuming you stayed consistent with the old illustration). The path between these nodes is `8 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3`, thus the distance is 4.

Comment: @Sirupsen Now your derivation is incorrect, you mix up d(8,2) and d(8,3).

Comment: @Sirupsen No, `d(8,3) = d(8) + d(3) - 2 * d(lca(8,2))` it should be `lca(8,3)` on the RHS there, and moreover `lca(8,3)==1` so `d(lca(8,3))==0`.

Comment: @Sirupsen Why?  It seems you've just made a simple error, mixing up nodes.  We all do it!  I think my last comment on top of everything else makes the situation clear.

Comment: Well you're talking about it like it's terribly obvious that 1 is the lowest common ancestor which I don't think it is in a graph where the root shouldn't matter. :-) Since if you rotated the graph clockwise, 2 works. But I guess it seems to be due to this algorithm being root-dependent, otherwise I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Ok you're right. :-) I had my definition out the window.. the lowest common ancestor is the vertex with the smallest relative depth to some fixed root between the two vertices in the graph. I think I was confusing it with the midpoint of the path between the two vertices. If you update your answer according to the new illustration, and just point out that part is wrong I'll go ahead and accept it. Thank you!